# In Selenium 2: driver.switchTo().frame() causes Application to crash

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium 2 and IE7.

There are a lot of iframes present in the application I am testing.
So I am using `driver.switchTo().frame()` method to switch between iframes.
I also use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` before switching to an iframe.

However in some cases, `driver.switchTo().frame()` causes the Application to crash.
Below is the error in eclipse:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: javaw.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.70.6
  Application Timestamp:    484e4780
  Fault Module Name:    IEDriver.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4fdf5b90
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0008a71e
  OS Version:   6.0.6001.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 1699
  Additional Information 2: 3c7b32a427f0a23d017c01e406809b93
  Additional Information 3: 437a
  Additional Information 4: 0abbaf052c4358d69b1ef6b054f6ab09
```

I even tried getting the source of the iframe by, `driver.findElement(By.id(iframeID)).getAttribute("src")`, and i am able to get the source of iframe.
I have also tried to introduce wait between switching of iframes but still it gives the same error.
I do not know why it is causing the application to crash as it is working for some cases.

Does anyone have any similar experience or can think of any solution??

Comment: in my experience IEDriver isn't stable at all so maybe that's the only problem with it... can you nevertheless offer some code?

Comment: What version of Selenium WebDriver are you using? You should also be using the IEDriverServer.exe instead of the internal .dll.

Comment: @Frank, I strongly disagree with your characterization of the IEDriver being "[not] stable at all". If you have encountered specific, reproducible issues, I'm sure the development team would be eager to hear about them.

Comment: @JimEvans In general I'm a huge fan of the whole Selenium project- especially the WebDriver. I know that Mozilla provides a lot better integration for Selenium- it's the old problem with Microsoft. But from my point of view, if an automated workflow works with FF but works not with IE that's not my fault (with few exceptions). Also that IE has problems with session handling and the oft- cited cursor problem do their bit. That are the main reasons we have to do IE testing only separately triggered and not as part of std testing.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to choose iframe by src and it works:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src=\"SRC_OF_FRAME\"]")));
```